# gradle: custom jar task

Tags: jar, gradle

I feel like I am missing something obvious here, but I can't seem to find it.

I have a project, where I want my package structure like so

```
/src
    /webapp
        /webapp-package-1
        /webapp-package-2
    /iface
        /iface-package-1
        /iface-package-2
```

I want to define a task that packages up the classes for iface and makes it into a jar.  So I followed the user guide here: http://www.gradle.org/0.8/docs/userguide/userguide_single.html#configureSourceSet (I am using version 0.8).

I now have this,

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
    intTest {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/iface/'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'test'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}


task intTestJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: intTestClasses) {
    from sourceSets.intTest.classes
}
```

And can verify that the classes in `intTest` are being built appropriately in `/build/classes/intTest`.  However, trying to invoke the `intTestJar` always gives me this warning:

```
[ant:jar] Warning: skipping jar archive C:\workspace\foo\build\libs\foo-1.0.jar because no files were included.
```

I don't understand this, because the classes are being created successfully.  Also, the full build task creates the entire jar successfully.

Ideas?

Comment: I may be wrong, but  your project appears to be a good candidate for a multi-project gradle config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution appears to work with the latest version of Gradle(0.9.2). I ran the intTestJar task exactly as shown above(adding the java plugin of course) on this file tree:

```
└── iface
    └── ifacePackageOne
        ├── Test.java
        └── testFile.txt
```

and here's the resulting jar structure:

```
├── META-INF
│   └── MANIFEST.MF
└── iface
    └── ifacePackageOne
        ├── Test.class
        └── testFile.txt
```

So the short answer - try a newer version of Gradle. http://gradle.org/

Comment: Shoot.  I was hoping to stay on .8 until 1.0 hit, because there were small syntax changes and we already have a few projects using gradle which would need updated if my team upgraded to .9, and it's not very easy to straddle two gradle versions at once.  This might force me over the line though.  Thanks.

Comment: @lucas: consider using the gradle wrapper. It should allow you to not have to worry so much about versions and upgrading.